# Browser indicates: Can't Find Variable: $?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, canvasjs

I am very new to javascript (jquery/json) I have written this code to render a chart of `CanvasJS` with a php/json data fetching script along with it.

However the chart won't show, when I implement my code in to it. When I used `Console.log()` in web browser to find the ReferenceError it says: `Can't find variable: $ ...Chart.html:11`

I have tried many things and I have read many [duplicate] question/answers saying that I didn't load the Jquery Library and a bunch of other options. I have tried implementing this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

And I have tried many variables, but I don't think I understand what I can use more in these two codes I have..

Any point into the right direction would be great.

**Chart.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>


<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function () {

                $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

                var dataPoints = [];

                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
                }

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                data: [
                {
                dataPoints: dataPoints
                }
                ]
                });

                chart.render();
                });
        });


</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, it concerns this part:

> $(document).ready(function () {

and my php for the JSON data fetching: **data.php**

```
 <?php
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","WebApplication");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } 
    else
    {
    $data_points = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM info");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {        
        $point = array("x" => $row['id'] , "y" => $row['acceleration']);

        array_push($data_points, $point);        
    }

        $json =  json_encode($data_points, 32); //define('JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK',32);   // Since PHP 5.3.3
        $json = str_replace("\"", "", $json); //replace all the "" with nothing
         echo $json;

    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

I know that the stack overflow community always require **more** info, but for god sake, I don't know anymore, and I really want to learn this.

**EDIT-1:**

This is what I have know, yet no result.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function () {

                $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

                var dataPoints = [];

                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
                }

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                data: [
                {
                dataPoints: dataPoints
                }
                ]
                });

                chart.render();
                });
        });


</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT-2:DEFAULT CODE, WHICH WORKS:**

This is the default code that doesn't use my data.php code and uses randomized data points as data-source. It's from Canvasjs and it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

        var dps = []; // dataPoints

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            title :{
                text: "Patient #01"
            },          
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dps 
            }]
        });

        var xVal = 0;
        var yVal = 100; 
        var updateInterval = 20;
        var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

        var updateChart = function (count) {
            count = count || 1;
            // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
                yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
                dps.push({
                    x: xVal,
                    y: yVal
                });
                xVal++;
            };
            if (dps.length > dataLength)
            {
                dps.shift();                
            }

            chart.render();     

        };

        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 

        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 

    }

</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:600px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the two `<script>` tags *inside* the `<head>`, also if `canvasjs` relies on jQuery, you should put `jquery.js` *first* in the list.

Comment: Place JQuery library above the other JS file

Comment: Should I change document within the braces, into for instance JSON (variable)?

Comment: So something along the lines of:  $(json).ready(function ()

Comment: Did you verify that the url to the jquery.min.js is valid?

Comment: Yes I did. I use that one also for another javascript code I made yesterday and that works good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like jQuery is being loaded after canvasJS. If Canvasjs needs to use jQuery, it will need to have jQuery loaded first. Try switching those lines so jQuery is loaded on top, and it will probably fix your error.

**EDIT:** Actually, it seems that the CDN that hosts your jQuery doesn't use $ as the name of your main jQuery object. If you change $ to "jQuery" that error should be resolved. For example:

```
$(document).ready
```

would become:

```
jQuery(document).ready
```

same with $.getJson

Comment: Wow, I didn't know the code was that sensitive, but it seems logical. i'll try it out :)

Comment: That was my first thought as well but the error message is on the online script on the hot enough $().ready call. I rather think it's because the script tags are outside of the head or body tags. Edit: wrote this before update of post.

Comment: So there are a few issues in here. You will want your script tags that load both jquery and the canvasjs in your head, rather than above it. For the most part, however, this is a bit less than ideal. This is because Javascript is blocking when it loads, meaning that it is going to stop the rest of the page from loading. The $document(ready) function script block should also be moved below the body (that function runs once the dom finished loading, meaning all the code in the body has been interpreted.)

Comment: you may also try changing "$" to "jQuery" as it looks as that cdn uses jQuery as the name of the main function, rather than $. For example  jQuery(document).ready

Comment: John, do you mean $ as in $(document) part? into JQuery?

Comment: yeah, it's worth a shot! You wouldn't change the php variables. Just any javascript that references $ as the  jQuery object. so:  
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

Comment: I'll try it out!  In the meantime, I have uploaded the default code from CanvasJS in EDIT-2 above.

Comment: I tried the jQuery thing you said, however to no avail :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80111/discussion-between-john-stringer-and-mieer-darwesh).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jquery isn't being loaded properly, and I'm thinking it's because of your unconventional practice of including the external scripts directly after the  element. Try moving them down to just before your own script, inside the head.

Edit: the post was updated and apparently this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLVED IT**

First include this line:

than include this line:  BELOW the code, not above it.

Than go to my data.php and comment (or delete) this line: //$json = str_replace("\"", "", $json); //replace all the "" with nothing

why u ask? Well because CanvasJS requires Strings and not separate characters/integrers.

So that the output will be:

> [{"x":"1","y":"5"},{"x":"2","y":"5"},{"x":"3","y":"4"},{"x":"4","y":"1"},{"x":"5","y":"8"},{"x":"6","y":"9"},{"x":"7","y":"5"},{"x":"8","y":"6"},{"x":"9","y":"4"},{"x":"10","y":"7"},{"x":"14","y":"7"},{"x":"15","y":"7"}]

Instead of:

> [{x:1,y:5},{x:2,y:5},{x:3,y:4},{x:4,y:1},{x:5,y:8},{x:6,y:9}...etc.